# Set of sequences summing to $0$ is dense in $\ell_2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $M_2 := \{ (x_i) \in \ell_2 : \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i = 0\}$. I want to show that $\operatorname{cl} M_2 = \ell_2$ using the following definition of closure:

$$\operatorname{cl} A := \{x\in \ell_2 : \forall \varepsilon > 0 : B_{\varepsilon}(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset\}$$

where $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ is the open ball of radius $\varepsilon$ around $x$.

So given $x\in \ell_2$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ I need to find a $y\in M_2$ with $\| x - y\|_2 <\varepsilon$. I don't have any clue what kind of theorem I could use to establish the existence of such a $y$. How can I prove this?

Comment: A bit of clarification: I was only able to find the question that I marked as possible duplicate *after* posting this question (it was suggested to me under "Related" questions)

Comment: This first answer to the linked question shows $M_2^\perp$, the orthogonal complement of $M_2$, is $\{0\}$. Since $\{0\}$ is a closed subvectorspace we have $\ell_2 = M_2^\perp \oplus M_2^{\perp \perp} = \operatorname{cl}(M_2)$ (because $\ell_2$ is a Hilbert space).